# How to send both video & image file at once in Java?

Tags: java, video, audio, io

I am doing client server socket programing in Java using `fileinput` reader and `buffer` reader which is connected to each other. But buffer reader has a method read or readline where only one line we can read from file.

Can we able to read whole content all at once using buffer? Which function is suitable or which class I can use? I want to send both video and image file - how to send these files ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading video or image data, you should not be using the `Reader` classes at all, they're for text data.

For binary data, you have to use a `FileInputStream` and its [`read()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) method, which you'll have to use in a loop, paying attention to its return value.

Alternatively, use a library that already implements this, sucht as [`FileUtils.readFileToByteArray()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToByteArray%28java.io.File%29) of Apache Commons IO.

Comment: michael thank full for ur use full information..i hav one more problem..please can u try to solve it...am sending a 27kb image file..but at the server end am not able to get the same size file..i ll get a file at server end but i can open it..here s my coe just go through tis..

Comment: client code..                                             FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Blue hills.jpg"); DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
byte[] buffer=new byte[1000];
int bytes=0;

while ((bytes = fstream.read(buffer)) != -1){
 output.write(buffer,0,bytes); //wher output is a variable connected to server socket
 }

Comment: @rajesh: that code looks OK - do you close the output stream after the loop? BTW, the Apache Commons class I linked to also has methods for copying between streams.